# Could Video4Linux (V4L) usb camera worked with Jetson TX2 running ROS Kinetic?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, jetson

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Below please find my proposed setup:

1. Board version --> Nvidia Jetson TX2
2. OS version --> Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
3. ROS version --> Kinetic Kame
4. ROS package for V4L driver --> usb_cam
5. V4L utilities Ubuntu package that used by usb_cam --> v4l-utils
6. ROS package for interface btw ROS and OpenCV --> cv_bridge

My application requirement is to use a Video4Linux (V4L) vision camera to take a footage. The footage will be handled by the usb_cam node and publishes as a ROS image message. The ROS image message is converted into the OpenCV image data via cv_bridge node. The OpenCV image data can then be analyzed for pattern recognition or other purpose.

I have tried all these on a laptop and is functioning, will it work under Jetson TX2.

Many thanks for your kind advise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289081/could-video4linux-(v4l)-usb-camera-worked-with-jetson-tx2-running-ros-kinetic?/) by [KokLeong](https://answers.ros.org/users/34707/kokleong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-19**:
Why did you delete your previous question? You can edit your question next time instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a setup with Ubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic, and using usb_cam, that definitely works on the TX2. You'd have to check for the cv_bridge, especially if you use OpenCV4Tegra, but you can also install [OpenCV](https://github.com/jetsonhacks/buildOpenCVTX2) now.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) with karma: 157 on 2018-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KokLeong](https://answers.ros.org/users/34707/kokleong/) on 2018-04-22**:
Hi Cyril,

Many thanks for your kind sharing.
Have a good week.

BR,
Kok Leong